# SQL Fill in blank data based on previous rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, sql-update

I have a SQL Table that is similar to the following:

```
ID, Date,   D1, D2, D3
1   1/1/13  0   X   A
2   1/2/13          
3   1/3/13  1
4   1/4/13          B
5   1/5/13
```

that I need to update to the following:

```
ID, Date,   D1, D2, D3
1   1/1/13  0   X   A
2   1/2/13  0   X   A       
3   1/3/13  1   X   A   
4   1/4/13  1   X   B
5   1/5/13  1   X   B
```

Basically filling in all the nulls with the value before it. This is only going to be performed once. Would a loop be the best option? Or is there something that would be more effective?

Comment: What rdbms are you using?

Comment: Are you defining previous as "With the next lowest `ID` value"? Or "With the next lowest `Date` value"? Or do you have some other definition you want to use? Tables are inherently unordered. If you're wanting to do something that involves order, you have to give us an explicit rule to define that order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presuming that you're using SQL-Server you can use this common-table-expression:

```
WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT T1.id, 
                T1.date, 
                d1 = COALESCE(T1.d1, (SELECT TOP 1 d1 
                                      FROM   dbo.tablename T2 
                                      WHERE  T2.id < T1.id  
                                             AND d1 IS NOT NULL 
                                      ORDER  BY id DESC)), 
                d2 = COALESCE(T1.d2, (SELECT TOP 1 d2 
                                      FROM   dbo.tablename T2 
                                      WHERE  T2.id < T1.id 
                                             AND d2 IS NOT NULL 
                                      ORDER  BY id DESC)), 
                d3 = COALESCE(T1.d3, (SELECT TOP 1 d3 
                                      FROM   dbo.tablename T2 
                                      WHERE  T2.id < T1.id
                                             AND d3 IS NOT NULL 
                                      ORDER  BY id DESC)) 
         FROM   dbo.tablename T1) 
UPDATE T 
SET    T.d1 = C.d1, 
       T.d2 = C.d2, 
       T.d3 = C.d3 
FROM   dbo.tablename T 
       INNER JOIN cte C 
               ON T.id = C.id 
WHERE  T.d1 IS NULL 
        OR T.d2 IS NULL 
        OR T.d3 IS NULL
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/75874/9/0)

**Edit** Since you have mentioned in the comments that you have `''` instead of `null`, here is a modified version that supports both:

```
WITH cte AS 
        (SELECT T1.id, 
                T1.date, 
                d1 = CASE WHEN COALESCE(T1.d1, '') <> '' THEN d1 
                       ELSE(SELECT TOP 1 d1 
                            FROM   dbo.tablename T2 
                            WHERE  T2.id < T1.id 
                                   AND COALESCE(T2.d1, '') <> '' 
                            ORDER  BY T2.id DESC) END, 
                d2 = CASE WHEN COALESCE(T1.d2, '') <> '' THEN d2 
                       ELSE(SELECT TOP 1 d2 
                            FROM   dbo.tablename T2 
                            WHERE  T2.id < T1.id 
                                   AND COALESCE(T2.d2, '') <> '' 
                            ORDER  BY T2.id DESC) END, 
                d3 = CASE WHEN COALESCE(T1.d3, '') <> '' THEN d3 
                       ELSE(SELECT TOP 1 d3 
                            FROM   dbo.tablename T2 
                            WHERE  T2.id < T1.id 
                                   AND COALESCE(T2.d3, '') <> '' 
                            ORDER  BY T2.id DESC) END 
         FROM   dbo.tablename T1) 
UPDATE T 
SET    T.d1 = C.d1, 
       T.d2 = C.d2, 
       T.d3 = C.d3 
FROM   dbo.tablename T 
       INNER JOIN cte C 
               ON T.id = C.id 
WHERE  COALESCE(T.d1, '') = '' 
        OR COALESCE(T.d2, '') = '' 
        OR COALESCE(T.d3, '') = ''
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/97830/1/0)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why `T2.id <= T1.id - 1` rather than `T2.id < T1.id`?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Yes, that was a leftover from my first version which didn't use `<=` but `=` and also didn't have the `WHERE` + `ORDER BY`. (Edited)

Comment: Works, except my nvarchar columns are actually '' and not null. Is there any way to modify this to work for that? I could run an update script before this to change the ''s to actual NULLS I suppose.

Comment: @Shawn: you have mentioned nulls in your question. However, in general it is better to use null if a value is undefined. Im on the road now, so I cannot show you a different way.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter Agreed, I didn't realize they were empty strings until this point. I'll try to work on it.

Comment: Just ran a quick update statement to change the ''s to nulls before running an expanded version of this. Works great, thanks.

Comment: @Shawn: Wait a minute and i'll show you an approach that works with `''` **and** `nulls`. (... done)

Comment: @Tim Thanks, I appreciate your thoroughness.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we're using the `ID` column to determine order, you can do it without loops.

Whether you *want* to do this is another matter - it doesn't look pretty:

```
declare @t table (ID int, Date date,   D1 int, D2 char(1), D3 char(1))
insert into @t(ID, Date,   D1, D2, D3) values
(1,'20130101',0,'X','A'),
(2,'20130201',null,null,null),     
(3,'20130301',1,null,null),
(4,'20130401',null,null,'B'),
(5,'20130501',null,null,null)

update a
set
    a.D1 = COALESCE(a.D1,d1.D1),
    a.D2 = COALESCE(a.D2,d2.D2),
    a.D3 = COALESCE(a.D3,d3.D3)
from
    @t a
        left join
    @t D1
        on
            D1.ID < a.ID and
            D1.D1 IS NOT NULL
        left join
    @t D1_anti
        on
            D1_anti.ID < a.ID and
            D1_anti.D1 is not null and
            D1_anti.ID > D1.ID
        left join
    @t D2
        on
            D2.ID < a.ID and
            D2.D2 IS NOT NULL
        left join
    @t D2_anti
        on
            D2_anti.ID < a.ID and
            D2_anti.D2 is not null and
            D2_anti.ID > D2.ID
        left join
    @t D3
        on
            D3.ID < a.ID and
            D3.D3 IS NOT NULL
        left join
    @t D3_anti
        on
            D3_anti.ID < a.ID and
            D3_anti.D3 is not null and
            D3_anti.ID > D3.ID
where
    D1_anti.ID is null and
    D2_anti.ID is null and
    D3_anti.ID is null

select * from @t
```

Basically, we perform joins to try to find earlier rows which may be applicable, and then perform the `_anti` joins to make sure that each found earlier row is the latest such row that exists.